# Jenkins missing config.xml of Jobs under windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, continuous-integration, config

I got a Problem with our Jenkins Server:

The Config.xml files for the jobs are missing after some time and we dont know why.
I'm rather sure that noone is deleting the files.

I already uninstalled the Plugin `email-ext` as I first noticed missing jobs after I first installed the Plugin.

However this morning there was again 1 config.xml missing.

Jenkins Version is 1.598 and its running under win7.

I appreciate any hints on what could be the source of my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to see which process deletes xml files.